# Video Streaming 500 error in production (NextJS)

Tags: node.js, video, next.js, video-streaming

I have been developing this site: https://mirobod-tumani.vercel.app. On the home page there is a video background. To optimize the initial load, i optimized the video itself and  decided to stream it.
This is the code:

```
// pages/api/video

import fs from 'fs'

export default function handler(req, res) {
if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const range = req.headers.range
    const videoPath = 'public/assets/mirobod.webm'
    const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size
    const chunkSize = 1 * 1e6
    const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ''))
    const end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, videoSize - 1)
    const contentLength = end - start + 1
    const headers = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'video/webm',
    }
    res.writeHead(206, headers)
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end })
    stream.pipe(res)
}
```

```
// pages/index.js

<video autoPlay muted loop>
 <source src='/api/video' type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

Locally, when i navigate to root `localhost:3000/` it is working as i expect,
but when i try to open that `/api/video` api differently, for example, when i navigate to `localhost:3000/api/video` or call it in Postman, there is an error saying `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`, i undestand that `req.headers.range` is `undefined`. Also in production there is a 500 error with that api and not showing the video as you can see from the site link above.

**I tried**:

```
if(!req.headers.range) // send the whole video at one

else ...
```

But in this case, this is not what i want from streaming and also this leads [Exceeding Serverless Function Payload Size Limit](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#serverless-function-payload-size-limit)

So what is the problem, what should i do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, posting it for anyone having the same issue.

For what i understood by this https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.27

`req.headers.range` may be not set for the initial request and be available during stream goes.
Actually, initial range is equal to 'bytes=0-', and updates during the stream depending on your defined chunk size

[image]

**So it did**:

```
let range = req.headers.range
if(!range) range = 'bytes=0-'

...
```

**But there still was a problem**
I thought it was about the path, then i changed this:

```
const videoPath = 'public/assets/mirobod.webm'
```

to this:

```
const videoName = 'mirobod.webm'
const videoPath = path.resolve('public/assets/', videoName)
```

**And it succeeded!**

Answer (score 0):

As the error explains you are running into limits of how much a free vercel function can execute - Video streaming is better handled with a host or a bucket that can handle that transmission - I would suggest hosting it elsewhere like https://cloudinary.com/pricing with a free plan

As of this post, the free plan offers enough of what you need

> 25K transformations or
> 25 GB of managed storage or
> 25 GB of net viewing bandwidth

Developing a streaming video solution requires associated resources, the host you are deploying code to isn't supposed to solve for Video streaming in the free version.